# Metrics with infinite distances.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition

I've been wondering about the spaces $\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ and $\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}.$ Is there a useful generalization of the definition of a metric they satisfy? I thought it would be natural to define a "metric" $d$ in the same way as a usual, but adding $+\infty$ to its possible values and doing some tweaking to weaken the requirement that $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y.$ I can't see why it wouldn't be OK, but I haven't been able to find anything about it anywhere. Is such a notion used? Or a similar one?

Comment: The [extended real number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) might interest you.

Comment: @GitGud Well, I know what the extended real line is. But as the article says, there is no metric on that space that is an extension of the usual metric on the real line. So I wonder why wouldn't we just generalize the notion of a metric.

Comment: In this case, what would be $d(+\infty, -\infty)$?

Comment: @Gustavo It seems natural to make it $\infty.$ There would of course be some trouble with $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$, but I think it should be possible to get around that, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think the problem might lie in something to do with $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(n,2n)$ and $d(\infty,\infty)$. On the one hand, distances tend to $\infty$, while on the right, by definition it is $0$.

Comment: I guess I would ask what value would there be in using the extended real line as distance values? For the most part, using a distance $d$ and a modified distance $d_*(x,y) = \min(d(x,y),1)$ produces the same results, so I don't see room for much improvement.

Comment: For any $r \in \mathbb{R}$ your metric should give $d(r, \infty) = d(r, -\infty) = \infty$. That will be an interesting function.

Comment: @copper.hat if you are only interested in the topology induced by the metric then it indeed won't matter. But if you are interested in metric properties then this construction drastically changes the metric. Another reason to allow infinite distance is that the category of metric spaces without distance infinity does not have coproducts and similar constructions, while allowing infinite distance corrects that problem.

Comment: @clayton the problem you point to doesn't really exist. The sequence $x_n=n$ diverges to $\infty$, it does not converge. So the continuity of the distance function does not imply $d(\infty ,\infty ) \ne 0$.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: But by the definition, $d(a,a)=0$, isn't this why $d(\infty,\infty)=0$ necessary? That was my thought on it.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: I appreciate the categorical intellectual closure of extended metrics, but the utility escapes me. (But then, my background is in engineering...)

Comment: @clayton the distance function being continuous means that if $x_n$ converges to $x$, $y_n$ converges to $y$, then $d(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $d(x,y)$. But $x_n=n$ does not converge to $\infty $, it diverges to $\infty$. So, indeed by definition $d(\infty , \infty)=0$, but it does not contradict anything.

Comment: @copper.hat well, isn't it convenient to know that if you have two metric spaces, that you can speak of their disjoint union *without* distorting any of the given metrics?

Comment: @IttayWeiss: :-).

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Since we're in the extended real line, doesn't $x_n=n$ converge to infinity, since any open set containing $\infty$ contains almost all positive integers?

Comment: given $\infty > \epsilon >0$ there is no $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ holds that $|x_n-\infty |<\epsilon$, cause $|n-\infty |=\infty $. In other words, $\infty $ is an isolated point since $d(x,\infty )=\infty $ for all $x\ne \infty $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing the distance function in a metric to assume the value $\infty$ is done often and is very useful. In fact, what you suggest can be carried through much more generally. You can define the notion of a metric taking values in what is known as a value quantale. See the article "Quantales and continuity spaces" by Robert Flagg (Algebra Universalis).